# Как перевести рандомный символ в верхний регистр в строке?

Tags: c++, строки

Как перевести рандомный символ в верхний регистр в строке?

Тип строки std::string

Comment: если бы не слово "рандомный", то все просто. "Рандомный" - это выбранный случайно, или со случайным значением?...

Comment: используйте `std::toupper`